# Initializing chromium cause app ANR

Tags: java, android, webview

Question :

Recently, I have a problem about android anr and It have troubled me for days.It happens when a webview object is about to create at first time of app first running after installed sometimes not every time!!!. It happened on android 4.4 and above.

Personal Analysis:

The orignal question is that my app sometime become anr when I try init a third sdk and I'm pretty sure that It's not my code cause this.I checked the `/data/anr/traces.txt`and analysis the log when anr happened(As follows).

```
01-14 14:14:38.933 17851-17851/com.xxx.xxx.XXX I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.chrome version 55.0.2883.91 (code 288309102)
01-14 14:14:38.964 17851-17851/com.xxx.xxx.XXX I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 4 ms (timestamps 8842-8846)
01-14 14:14:38.964 17851-17851/com.xxx.xxx.XXX I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "55.0.2883.91", actual native library version number "55.0.2883.91"
01-14 14:14:38.968 17851-17851/com.xxx.xxx.XXX I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "55.0.2883.91", actual native library version number "55.0.2883.91"
01-14 14:14:38.969 17851-17851/com.xxx.xxx.XXX I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(163)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
01-14 14:15:40.092 17851-17856/com.xxx.xxx.XXX I/art: Thread[2,tid=17856,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xa950d000,peer=0x12c26280,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
01-14 14:15:40.224 17851-17856/com.xxx.xxx.XXX I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-14 14:16:45.201 17851-20383/com.xxx.xxx.XXX W/cr_ChildProcLauncher: Create a new ChildConnectionAllocator with package name = com.android.chrome, inSandbox = true
01-14 14:16:45.201 17851-17851/com.xxx.xxx.XXX I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=false
```

And following is the normal log.

```
01-16 14:49:03.641 4032-4032/com.xxx.xxx.XXX I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:57082043
01-16 14:49:03.932 4032-4032/com.xxx.xxx.XXX I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 45.0.2454.95 (code 246109560)
01-16 14:49:04.004 4032-4032/com.xxx.xxx.XXX I/cr.library_loader: Time to load native libraries: 43 ms (timestamps 2362-2405)
01-16 14:49:04.004 4032-4032/com.xxx.xxx.XXX I/cr.library_loader: Expected native library version number "", actual native library version number ""
01-16 14:49:04.018 4032-4032/com.xxx.xxx.XXX V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider: Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {10aaffa1}
01-16 14:49:04.018 4032-4032/com.xxx.xxx.XXX I/cr.library_loader: Expected native library version number "", actual native library version number ""
01-16 14:49:04.024 4032-4032/com.xxx.xxx.XXX I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(121)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
01-16 14:49:04.038 4032-4032/com.xxx.xxx.XXX I/cr.BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
```

As we can see.The app takes nearly two minutes here to Inilializing chromium process and trapped the ui thread and finally cause anr.Why I am pretty sure It's the chromium that caused the anr because I tried to remove the third sdk,and just new a webview object as `Webview wv = new Webview(this);` in `onCreate()` of `MainActivity.java` .I still get the anr and same err log.

Tried ways:

1. Someone said that the version of webview should be changed.So on android 7.0,I recover chrome version to a lower one.On android 5.1, I recover `android system webview` version to a lower one. It did not work.
2. I have a blocked network visiting `google.com`.So I think It may cause the problem and I use a network proxy which can visit `google.com` and It do work for me.The anr do not happened any more.

Conclusion:

It pretty little that I can do .In fact, what really confused me is that it seems to be a really common problem but I did not find any relative material on network or some people that have the same problem. Any answer or experience would be helpful.